# Getstream.io get like count and users who liked

Tags: flutter, kotlin, getstream-io

My add like function looks like this (**kotlin**)

```
private fun addLike(user: String, token: String, activityID: String) {
    val client = CloudClient.builder(API_KEY, token, user).build()
    val like = Reaction.Builder().kind("like").activityID(activityID).build()
    client.reactions().add(user, like).join()
}
```

and the read is:

```
private fun getActivitiesForTeam(user: String, token: String, team: String): List<EnrichedActivity> {
    val client = CloudClient.builder(API_KEY, token, user).build()
    return client.flatFeed(team, "messages")
            .getEnrichedActivities(Limit(25), EnrichmentFlags().withOwnReactions().withRecentReactions().withReactionCounts()).join()
}
```

When I got the **latest_reactions_extra** field this will be:

**latest_reactions_extra  {}**  // I think this will be the empty

or

**latest_reactions_extra  {like: {next: }}**  //this is the not empty? But why is it nullstring?

So how can I get the like count and the users who liked?

Also how can I delete that like? I got nothing like a 'reactionID' but the docs says it will be something called **reactionID**

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
private fun addLike(user: String, token: String, activityID: String) {
    val client = CloudClient.builder(API_KEY, token, user).build()
    val like = Reaction.Builder().kind("like").activityID(activityID).userID(user).build()
    client.reactions().add(user, like).get()
}
```

**result.success(ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(reaction))**

when I modified the addLike function to this, I got this:

latest_reactions_extra  {like: {next: https://stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/reaction/activity_id/34oijgiojiojgiojijoijoij-tgrgrtgrtgt/like/?id_lt=ergerg-01e1-4b73-b88d-regger&limit=5&withOwnChildren=false}}

What is this?

**SOLUTION**

**OK it looks like fasterxml ObjectMapper just erased/killed my reactions field, so I had to create the json string in an other way...:/**

Comment: Do you still experience a problem or is it resolved ?

Comment: @ferhatelmas resolved by myself. I needed to generate the json via kotlin to use it in dart/flutter. fasterxml killed the reactions list, so I just create the json myself with strings only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

OK it looks like fasterxml ObjectMapper just erased/killed my reactions field, so I had to create the json string in an other way...:/